# SETLL READE for a prefixed file

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have this weird problem while reading a file in an RPGLE program.

```
fmosdp00   if   e           k disk    prefix(xx:2)              

  SetLL ('HF':'30':'032':'SK':'0095320':'002':0:0001) mosdp00a; 
  Reade ('HF':'30':'032':'SK':'0095320':'002':0) mosdp00a;      

  *Inlr = *On;
```

The above SETLL and READE does not seem to set field values of MOSDP00 file as required.

When I run this program in Debug mode and do an EVAL XXMORD (field of MOSDP00) post the READE, it is blank.

But If i add some operation using any of these fields, for instance, DSPLY XXMORD, then the program seems to set this field value.

Can somebody help to understand this.

Comment: Maybe because you read MOSDP00A .... and you prefix MOSDP00

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The RPG compiler optimizes out variables that are not used. So in debug, if you try to view the value off a variable that is only implicitly defined by the record format, but not used in the program, you will not see a value. It is not an issue with prefixes. When you added the `DSPLY XXMORD` operation, you added a usage of the field, and this prevented the compiler from optimizing it out. This allows you to see the field in Debug. If you try another field on the record format that is not being used, it will again show blank in debug.

Comment: add the h-spec option `debug(*INPUT)` to have the compiler load all the fields.. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasd/hdebug.htm

Comment: also have a look at optimization option while compiling the module/program, we usually set it as *NONE during development.